# Can not parse Json with SharePoint 2013 over rest API on calender List

Tags: javascript, json, rest, sharepoint-2013

I tried read data from my SharePoint 2013 via REST API. But I have the problem that i get an error when read the data and transform it to Json.

On normal Sharepoint Lists i got no error and the script is working. But on the Calender List not and i can´t find the problem and i lost my complete hair....

```
  $.ajax({
url: requestUri,
type: "GET",
headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data){

var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);  
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
var results = jsonObject.d.results;

for(i = 0; i < results.length;i++) {

        console.log(results[i]["Title"])
    }    

},
error:  function(){
  alert("ERROR");
}
```

});

Here is the data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="http://XXXX/websites/IBFR/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>1960092e-a8ef-425b-bdcb-57c8005e3b8f</id><title /><updated>2018-01-11T15:59:33Z</updated><entry m:etag="&quot;7&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(15598)</id><category term="SP.Data.FortbildungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(15598)" /><title /><updated>2018-01-11T15:59:33Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Brandschutz - Auffrischung</d:Title></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;3&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(16068)</id><category term="SP.Data.FortbildungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(16068)" /><title /><updated>2018-01-11T15:59:33Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Brandschutz Grundkurs</d:Title></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(16069)</id><category term="SP.Data.FortbildungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'e1bb9ec0-2d0e-45f8-9ef8-bc4c70df815e')/Items(16069)" /><title /><updated>2018-01-11T15:59:33Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title>Brandschutz Grundkurs</d:Title></m:properties></content></entry></feed>
```

[image]

Comment: That data is XML, not JSON. And why would you stringify data only to parse it again? What is the output of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Why are you consuming XML as JSON over just using the XML or having the endpoint send JSON to begin with? Is data a string or an object to start with? Because if you stringify something that is already JSON, you'll double some escape characters, making JSON.parse after it throw an error. As written, jsonObject should be the same as data. SO maybe jsonObject = data works. Or the opposite, remove JSON.stringify and data is your string to start with.

Comment: i ve got a 401 in console.log(data);  because i query the prod system from my test-system i think that is the error.